How to define a typing special form for use with static type checking?
I would like to create a typing special form that takes a non-type, say integer, as an argument, similar to the 2nd argument of typing.Annotated.
For example, I'd like foo[5] to be the same type annotation as Annotated[int, 5].
There are many ways that don't fail at runtime, but are rejected by the type checker. I'm using mypy 1.11.1 - latest version at this time.
import typing

class foo:
   def __class_getitem__(cls, param: int):
      return typing.Annotated[int, param]

foo5 : foo[5]

mypy doesn't like it:
"foo" expects no type arguments, but 1 given  [type-arg]
Invalid type: try using Literal[5] instead?  [valid-type]

Using _SpecialForm:
@typing._SpecialForm
def bar(_self, param : int):
    return typing.Annotated[int, param]

bar5 : bar[5]

Nope:
Too many arguments for "_SpecialForm"  [call-arg]
Function "ex_typing_1.bar" is not valid as a type  [valid-type]
Perhaps you need "Callable[...]" or a callback protocol?
Invalid type: try using Literal[5] instead?  [valid-type]

Even the parenthesized syntax I don't care much for is no-go:
def baz(param : int):
    return typing.Annotated[int, param]

baz5 : baz(5)

Sez mypy:
Invalid type comment or annotation  [valid-type]
Suggestion: use baz[...] instead of baz(...)


as far as I am aware, you cannot define your own special forms such that they will be understood by third party static analysis tools, at least not generically

You can't define new special forms on your own. They are at the very root of the type system and type checkers' supports for them are specialized.
To quote the specification:


special form
A special form is an object that has a special meaning within the type system, comparable to a keyword in the language grammar.

— Glossary | Python typing spec

Regarding your attempts of constructing Annotated[] objects:

foo[5] fails because this syntax (where foo is a class) is reserved for parametrized generics, and 5 is not a valid type argument/type expression. Your __class_getitem__() implementation is simply ignored.

@typing._SpecialForm def bar(...) fails because _SpecialForm is just an internal marker signaling the type of special forms at runtime/when used as a value:
from typing import Annotated, Any, Generic, Literal

reveal_type(Annotated)  # _SpecialForm
reveal_type(Any)        # _SpecialForm
reveal_type(Generic)    # _SpecialForm
reveal_type(Literal)    # _SpecialForm


baz(5) fails because a call expression isn't a valid annotation expression.


See also Why doesn't Annotated[str, T] work while Annotated[T, str] works well?.
